# How to make input type number un-editable but still functioning?

Tags: html

```
<input readonly='readonly' id ='testid' name='testname' type='number' min ='1'>
```

I tried this one but not working. is there any way to do it? like using css or javascript.

my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmasejo/vta96mp1/

Comment: Define “functioning” and “not working”. Your example is a readonly field with no value set on it. You prevent the user from giving it a value and don’t set any initial value, so how do you expect it to function?

Comment: ahmm sorry for that. I just wanted to use a input type number that cant be edit, If i removed the read only it will work but you can edit the value.

Comment: that does not answer my question. If you mean that you want to prevent the user from *typing* a number, then you should say that in the question. (And that would mean deliberately reducing usability, but maybe this is a for a usability survey.)

Comment: what @JukkaK.Korpela means is that u have to use the `value="somthing"` in order for the input to function as u want ,because without it simply = null.

Comment: the best answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164278/disable-writing-in-input-type-number-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello I have a working code but i think this is not the best way. I merged the answer from

[How to disable backspace if anything other than input field is focused on using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645681/how-to-disable-backspace-if-anything-other-than-input-field-is-focused-on-using)

and the answer of TuomasK

here is the working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/vta96mp1/1/

**HTML**

```
<input class='testInput' id ='testid' value = '1' name='testname' type='number' min ='1'>
```

**JS**

```
$("#testid").keypress(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var elid = $(document.activeElement).hasClass('textInput');
   console.log(e.keyCode + ' && ' + elid);
    //prevent both backspace and delete keys
    if ((e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) && !elid) {
        return false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is from [Disable writing in input type number HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164278/disable-writing-in-input-type-number-html5), but it requires jQuery.

```
$("[type='number']").keypress(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Without jQuery code is: (input is an input field)

```
input.onkeypress=function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: If the question is about disabling typing, then the question should be closed as a duplicate instead of copying an answert.

Comment: hello thank you for answering it cant be edit but still can be deleted using backspace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It works for me.

```
$("#testid").keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46 ) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

  <input type="text" id="demo0">
  <input type="text" id="demo1">
  <input type="text" id="demo2" onkeypress="myFunction2()">


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("demo0").onkeypress = function() {
      myFunction0()
    };
    document.getElementById("demo1").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction1);

    function myFunction0() {
      document.getElementById("demo0").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }

    function myFunction1() {
      document.getElementById("demo1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

    function myFunction2() {
      document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>No text & number</h1>
  <div>
    <input id="ESP" type="number" name="ESP" onKeypress="event.preventDefault();">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```