# Can an `input` of type `number` be made untypeable?

Tags: html

I have this `input` tag:

```
<input id="coolTemperature" type="number" name="coolTemperature" min="60" max="90" placeholder="60-90F">
```

I want the user to be able to change this ONLY by clicking the up/down arrows included with the `input` box. I want the user to be unable to click inside the textbox to delete/edit the tag's contents.

Is this possible?

Comment: @j08691 if you're going to mark as duplicate at the very least link to a duplicate question.

Comment: @TylerSebastian - Do you not see the duplicate link?

Comment: I see that it is *A* duplicate but there is no linked answer.

Comment: This is the answer I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27740264/1435711