# Broswer prompts user before leving page if a form is filled up and not submited

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser

I have seen some sites that apparently execute some type of browser function that prompts the user if he/she wants to leave the page because there is a form not submitted:

**"This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."**

I know this can be programmed in JS, but is there a native function or option that suggests the browser to detect this kind of scenarios?

I believe there is one because I have seen several websites (like facebook) reacting in the same way and they all seem to use this kind of browser option.

like `autocomplete="on / off"` allows the browser to fill up a form or not automatically

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't something feature like autocomplete. But the website(s) you're referring to probably handle the same scheme - if a form or specific inputs are "dirty", and the user tries to leave the page, confirm it. But that's exclusively developed by the websites to correctly detect when to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
       window.onbeforeunload = function(){
           // Check the state of the form
            if(form_changed){
              return false;
            }else{
              return true;
            }

       };
   //]]>
</script>
```

When the function returns `false` to `window.onbeforeunload`, the browser automatically prompts the following question: **"This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."** (firefox)

Comment: I get an error when changing pages: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925111/activating-onbeforeunload-only-when-field-values-have-changed