# jQuery.one listening multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

jQuery's `$.fn.one` is supposed to be turned off after an event had been fired, and the listener had run the script.

However, if it's listening to multiple events, it won't turn off for all listened events after one of them firing.

Using this event listener:

```
var transitionend = "webkitTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend";

$( "foo" ).one( transitionend , function(){ 

   foo.bar(); 

} );
```

The `foo.bar()` method will be executed 2 times in chrome, since `webkitTransitionEnd`  `transitionend` both fire.

I am trying to achieve an **elegant** solution where firing one of the listened methods turns off all others in the listener.

Comment: You'd have better to normalize event to bind only the relevant one, as done using e.g Modernizr library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9090128/1414562  That's said, Carl's answer should work as expected, as i see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet may be to just manually remove the binding once the event has fired?

Somthing like:

```
var transitionend = "webkitTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend";
$( "foo" ).on( transitionend , function(){ 
   foo.bar(); 
   $(this).off(transitionend); 
} );
```

Edit: 
If you're after a more elegant looking solution (assuming you'd need to be doing this kinda thing a lot) it looks like someone has wrapped the above in to a reusable function on another Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589200/820822

Also: 
[jQuery's One - Fire once with multiple event types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589084/jquerys-one-fire-once-with-multiple-event-types/24589200) appears to be the same question, so may have some other useful answers.